btn.addEventListener('click', function() skips whole func but on the next usage working properly
i dont actually remember when it starts doing this, so zero clues for what causing this error
btn function is to take info from localstorage and then create a little card with info that i need to show
there is some of my code
JS
        if (error < 1) {
            let btn = document.getElementById('submit');
            btn.addEventListener('click',  function (event){
                event.preventDefault()
                const c = {
                    fond: document.getElementById("fond").value,
                    opis: document.getElementById("opis").value,
                    dela: document.getElementById("dela").value,
                    stdelo: document.getElementById("deloold").value,
                    fami: document.getElementById("surn").value,
                    name: document.getElementById("imya").value,
                    prime: document.getElementById("primechan").value,
                    bday: document.getElementById("bday").value,
                    bmonth: document.getElementById("bmonth").value,
                    byear: document.getElementById("byear").value,
                    ngorod: document.getElementById("gorod").value,
                    kolvolist: document.getElementById("kolvolist").value,
                    category: document.getElementById("zvan").value,
                    nprimechan: document.getElementById("primechan").value
                };
                const index = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userIndex')) || 1;
                localStorage.setItem('userIndex', index + 1);
                localStorage.setItem(`user${index}`, JSON.stringify(c));

                let dan = localStorage.getItem(`user${index}`);
                dan = JSON.parse(dan)

               Object.keys(dan).map(function () {
                   console.log(dan)
                    let surnam = `${dan["fami"]}`
                    let name = `${dan["name"]}`
                    let otchest = `${dan["prime"]}`
                    let fond = `${dan["fond"]}`
                    let opis = `${dan["opis"]}`
                    let dela = `${dan["dela"]}`
                    let data = `${dan['bday']}.${dan["bmonth"]}.${dan['byear']}`

                    let product = document.createElement('div')
                    product.classList.add(`user${index}`)
                    product.innerHTML =
                        `<div class="product">
                            <p class="product__title">${surnam}</p>
                            <p class="product__title">${otchest}</p>
                             <p class="product__title">${name}</p>
                            <p>Дата рождения: ${data}</p>
                            <p>Номер фонда: ${fond}</p>
                            <p>Номер описи: ${opis}</p>
                            <p>Номер дела: ${dela}</p>
                        </div>`

                    document.getElementById("formADD").reset();
                  const myData = new FormData(document.querySelector('.oknodel').append(product));
                    console.log(myData)
                });
            });
        }

